# set_3d_properties Attribute Error after updating conda to 4.9.2

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, conda

I am trying to save an animation using matplotlibs save function but was running into so errors and kept throwing up an error with Numpy. I went and update conda and the additional libraries to version 4.9.2 which all additional libraries at their latest version. Following that the animation no longer runs and I am hit continuously with the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 224, in process
func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1259, in _on_resize
self._init_draw()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1706, in _init_draw
self._drawn_artists = self._init_func()
File "c:\Users\matth\Google Drive\University\Year 3\Individual Project\Source Code\path-planning\genetic_algorithm_3d\genetic_algorithm_3D.py", line 111, in init
line.set_3d_properties([])
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\art3d.py", line 143, in set_3d_properties
zs = np.broadcast_to(zs, xs.shape)

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

A simplified version of the code that is causing the above error is as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as ani
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as p3

def init():
    line.set_data([], [])    
    line.set_3d_properties([])
    return line,


def animate(i, line, points):
    x = []
    y = []
    z = []
    for point in points[i]:
        x.append(point[0])
        y.append(point[1])
        z.append(point[2])

    line.set_data(x, y)
    line.set_3d_properties(z)
    return line,


start = [0, 1, 2]
goal = [10, 9, 6]
points = [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = p3.Axes3D(fig)

ax.plot([start[0]], [start[1]], [start[2]], 'gs')
ax.plot([goal[0]], [goal[1]],[goal[2]], 'ms')
line, = ax.plot([], [], [], lw=2, color="red")

# PLEASE NOTE that I do not intend for this simplified version of code to run correctly, just for the error to no longer exist
# hopefully this will at least help with understanding the issue
animation = ani.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, 50, init_func=init, fargs=(line, points), interval=500,   blit=True)

plt.show()
```

Like I mentioned, this was working before I updated conda but I am reluctant to just 'roll' back the versions without understanding why it is broken in the first place.

Any assistance on this would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

So after reviewing the docs related to matplotlib version 3.3.3 https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.Line3D.html?highlight=set_3d_properties#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.Line3D.get_data_3d, as highlighted by Matt Thompson, I noticed that method `set_data_3d` essentially replaced the method I was previously using so passing 3 empty arrays as input arguments into the method, `set_data_3d([], [], [])`, works perfectly.

Hopefully this helps anyone that that stumbles across this thread!

Answer (score 0):

The version of `conda` itself is extremely unlikely to be the source of the issue, it's the versions of the actual package that matter.

Regardless, the error is characteristic of a function expecting an array but finding a list. This may be an actual bug in `matplotlib` but the simplest change would probably be for you to do the conversion, like

```
    ...
    line.set_data(np.asarray(x), np.asarray(y))
    line.set_3d_properties(np.asarray(z))
    ...
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. Unfortunately that didnt seem to work - still raised the same error. Regarding the versions, I should have included them. Matplotlib is version 3.3.2. I am unsure what the previous version was, is there a way of checking the update log?

Comment: Here's the changelog  https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/users/whats_new.html#d-axes-improvements and API reference (possibly, I'm not actually sure which type you're operating on): https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.Line3D.html?highlight=set_3d_properties#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.Line3D.get_data_3d